# How to arrange selected vertices in a perfect circle

Tags: modifiers, vertices

[image]

So how do I get the surrounding vertices to make a circle (centered) without needing to manually move every single one to the right spot? Also I need the outer shape to stay as a square.

Comment: SHIFT + "A" > Choose Mesh from the drop down menu > Choose "Circle"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest method is to use the handy **LoopTools** addon which is already included in Blender. Just enable it in `User Preferences -> Add-ons`.

[image]

Comment: Where do I get this from? I have enabled LoopTools in the preference settings.

Comment: Found it, just had to press W

Comment: Or press T to open the left panel - it is located under Tools tab -> LoopTools.